# Where does cross compiler look for libraries?

Tags: c, linux, cross-compiling

When using cross compiler on Linux and defining `--host` option to `./configure`, where does it look for libraries? Can one define place where it should look for libs, headers, etc.?

Comment: As an aid to those answering this question, this page might be used as a reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Cross_002dCompilation.html

Comment: The linux from scratch project may also provide examples, they have a 'clfs' book (Ie, "cross linux from scratch")

Answer (score 0):

The --host flag is used to set up the platform where generated binaries will run. This --host flag is commonly used to configure cross compilation of  libs/bins, but is not used to generate the cross-compiler.

To use your cross-compiler you need to export some environ variables in your local environment (commonly CC, CXX, STRIP, AR, AS) pointing to your cross-tools (arm-linux-*). And after that, setup CFLAGS (-I) and LDFLAGS (-L) properly pointing to the rootfs of your cross-toolchain.